# MySQL как написать запрос поиска по нескольким ключевым словам

Tags: java, sql, spring-jpa

Есть таблица с вопросами. У вопросов есть поле "индексы", в котором через пробел перечисляются темы, к которым относится этот вопрос (каждая тема состоит из 1го слова). Я пытаюсь написать запрос, но никак не могу найти информацию, как передавать динамическое количество параметров в запрос. Ниже написан запрос для поиска по 1му ключевому слову. Как правильно изменить его, что бы он принимал в качестве параметра массив и выдавал все строки с хотя бы одним совпавшим значением?

```
@Query("select q from Question q where q.indexes like :idx")
List<Question> findByIdx(@Param("idx") String idx);
```

UPD: нашел, что можно напрямую передать Set, но это не работает. Возможно, я что-то упускаю? Программа компилируется, но поиск не работает.

```
@Query("select q from Question q where q.indexes like (:idx)")
List<Question> findByIdx(@Param("idx") Set<String> idx);
```

UPD2: нативный запрос с полнотекстовым поиском работает, но только если в сете только 1 элемент...

```
@Query(
       value = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE MATCH(indexes) AGAINST (+:idx IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<Question> findByIdx(@Param("idx") Set<String> idx);
```

Comment: *У вопросов есть поле "индексы", в котором через пробел перечисляются темы, к которым относится этот вопрос* Нормализуйте эту ерунду.

Comment: Я согласен с Akina, что это нужно нормализовать. | Как вариант вместо массива через пробел используйте json. По нему можно [искать](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: Я пока не думал над оптимизацией. Вопросов будет не так много, сомневаюсь, что их хотя бы за 1000 перевалит. Я хочу понять, можно ли передавать в качестве запроса массив и как это сделать. Спасибо за совет использовать json, я попробую, но мне в любом случае надо найти решение проблемы, описанной в вопросе.